# How do you interrogate an enemy?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

So I've completed the opening story mission where the wraith reads an orcs mind to gleen information. However I've not found a way to interrogate enemies when they are stunned.

Can you interrogate enemies 'manually'? If you can, what benefits does it bring?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can interrogate an enemy by grabbing them <kbd>RB</kbd> and then whilst holding them dominate <kbd>B</kbd> and interrogate <kbd>A</kbd>. Note captains and warchiefs may not be initially be grabbable and needs to be weakened first.

The benefits of interrogation depends on the type of enemy you are questioning:

- Normal uruk: Can give the name and appearance of an unknown captain (shown as black silhouette in the army screen)
- Worm (normal uruk with green icon on their head): Can give you the above information and the traits of the captain i.e. their strengths and weaknesses.
- Captains and warchiefs: may also be interrogated and will give the same information as worm. But often needs to be weakened first before you may grab them.

Note: If there are no more unknown information regarding captains or warchiefs, the interrogate option will be replaced by kill.

It is generally useful to know the strengths and weaknesses of a captain or warchief before engaging them in combat so that you may abuse their weaknesses and look out for their strengths.

Comment: Minor addition: if the version is PC, the controls are LCtrl to grab (hold it for a second), then Spacebar to dominate and again to interrogate. Also the green icon isn't just for uruk worms. Sometimes it's for Intel that can be picked up, and sometimes it's slave worms (although I think you need to do a few quests to unlock them) that you can get intel from if you free the slaves (i.e. kill all the surrounding uruks).

Comment: Slaves with valuable information show up in proportion to the number of missions you have done to free slaves.  On the PC version these show up as White Fists.